# The method 'toDate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: toDate()

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, datetime, mobile-application

```
Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 3),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Text(
                    DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(map['time'].toDate()) ,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),))
```

I'm showing the message date from firebase, when i send message to some one in the chat screen a red colored error displays first after the date is showing, how i can avoid this?

Comment: `map['time']` seems to be `null`.

Comment: @PeterKoltai but it is showing the date after 2 seconds of red screen error.

Comment: Sounds like you need a FutureBuilder or similar.

Comment: @WasibHussain Keep in mind that we can't see how you initialize `map`, so it's hard to say more than what Peter did. My guess is that your `map` comes from Firebase and thus is asynchronously loaded, but it'll be a lot more likely we can help if you can edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to show us the [minimal, **complete**/standalone code that would allow any of use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your map is async, and you are not waiting for it.
put an async where you are fetching the data.